# translate perl script removing control characters in script(1) output to sed

Tags: perl, bash, sed

I'm recording terminal sessions using the `script` command. Unfortunately the typescript output file contains many control-characters - for example from pressing the full screen command (<kbd>F11</kbd>) when in the vim editor or try it below.

```
script -f -t 2>${LOGNAME}-$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).time -a ${LOGNAME}-$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).session
vi abc.log
#write something and save
#:x to quit vi
ctrl + d to quit script
```

The script output `hostname-datetime.session` contais too many vi control-characters.

I found a perl script in [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2318/fix-a-typescript-file-created-by-the-script-program-to-remove-control-characters), which can remove these control characters from the typescript.
I am actually doing this replacement in C, and the program runs on a chroot envrioment, where the perl is not avaliable.

Question: Is there a a way to translate the following `perl` command to `sed` ?

```
cat typescript | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > typescript-processed
```

Comment: Please calrify what is the input, what is the current output, what is the desired output and most importantly, what is the problem? too many control-characters isn't a descriptive problem

Comment: I find that the perl one-liner combined with col -b, does a better job than other submitted solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well for me with GNU sed (or `gsed` on a Mac):

```
sed -re 's/\x1b[^m]*m//g' typescript | col -b
```

I created a sample typescript, and since I'm using a relatively advanced shell prompt, it's full of control characters, and the `perl` script in the OP doesn't actually work, so rather than converting I had to come up with my own.

Looking at the typescript with `hexdump -C`, it seems that all control sequences start with `\x1b` (the Escape character, or `^[`), and end with the letter "m". So in `sed` I use a simple replacement from `^[` until `m`, normally written as `\x1b.*?m` but since `sed` doesn't support the `?` symbol to make a pattern non-greedy, I used `[^m]*m` to emulate non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 2):

if you ONLY want printable ascii :

```
LC_ALL=C tr -cd ' -~\n\t' < typescript > typescript_printable_ascii_only
```

why this works? all printable ("normal") ascii are between Space and Tilde
And in addition you need Newline and Tab.
So `' -~\n\t'` covers all printable "normal" ascii characters. And `tr -d 'chars'` deletes all chars, `-c` takes the opposite of the range given (so everything except 'chars').

=> This `LC_ALL=C tr -cd ' -~\n\t'` deletes everything except the normal ascii characters (including newline and tab) (I force the locale to be 'C' to be sure we are in the right locale when calling "tr")

Comment: Note that in the case if VI editing... you may want to keep some of those ctrl characters. You can do a `cat -ve typescript` to try to determine which one you want, and add them within the tr range so that they are kept. Enter them in octal and preceded by an antislash: `\abc` (ex: `\377`, or `\011`)

Comment: ah, true : my `tr` will only take out the escape, which leaves behind the rest... sorry. It's best to match those escape codes entirely.